# Powershell script to check for reg key and copy a file or folder to location

Tags: powershell, batch-file, registry

Trying to write a script for Location based printing in a VDI environment.  Upon login to the VDI session, a network printer will get mapped based on the client's (thin/zero client) IP (using GPO). Based on that printer name (ie.'PRN-Printer1'), I need to copy a file from a share (\Server\share\printer1) to the local c:\drive\location. For 'PRN-Printer2', it will copy from \Server\share\printer2, etc..

I found a few scripts the check for the reg key and another that copies the files but I need some help putting it all together.  I am not an expert in scripting but I can fumble my way through some one liners.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is what I have so far...

Check registry (Not sure this is the best way to look for a key)

```
reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers  /f "PRN-" /t REG_SZ /s /k  | find "Name"
```

or

```
pushd;sl HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers; if(test-path PRN-){--???--}ELSE{"Printer does not exist"};popd
```

to copy the file:

```
ls "C:\drive\location" -r -i * | % {cp -force $_ ($_ -replace "c:\\drive\\location", "\\Server\share1")}
```

or

```
Copy-Item \\Server\Share\printer1\* C:\drive\location\
```

Not sure how to put this logic together or the best way to check for this printer in the registry since there could be multiple printers on the VDI session.

Basically, I need something that does:

If reg key (HCLM..) is 'PRN-printer1' then copy file(s) \Server\share\printer1 to c:\drive\location else... check for printer2....printer3...etc...

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get-Item to get list of all printers and store it in a variable $printername

```
$printername=(Get-Item "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\*").pschildname
```

Heres what you will have in $printername

```
PRN-printer1
PRN-printer2
PRN-printer3
```

Now for each $printer in $printername you can execute below script to copy files based on printer

```
ForEach($printer in $printername) {

if ($p -match  "PRN-printer1")

{
Copy-Item "\\Server\Share\printer1\*" "C:\drive\location"

}

elseif ($p -match  "PRN-printer1")

{

Copy-Item "\\Server\Share\printer2\*" "C:\drive\location"

}

elseif ($p -match  "PRN-printer1")

{

Copy-Item "\\Server\Share\printer2\*" "C:\drive\location"

}

}
```